# Get input approver user name in Jenkins Workflow plugin

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-workflow

I am trying to get userid who approved an "input" step in workflow jenkins groovy script. Below is the sample script

```
node('node1'){
    stage "test"

    input  message: 'test'
}
```

In the workflow UI if a person hits "thumbs up" I want to print his userid in the log. I dont see any option to do it.

```
def cause = currentBuild.rawBuild.getCause(Cause.UserIdCause)
cause.userId
```

will print the person who started the build. I have googled this for days but i am not finding anything. Any help here will be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 4):

This [Jira issue](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-31396) describes how this is likely to work going forward, however it is still open.

In the meantime, the approach of getting the latest ApproverAction via the build actions API was [suggested on #Jenkins IRC](https://botbot.me/freenode/jenkins/2015-10-23/?page=2) recently and should work, note it's not sandbox safe.

Something along the lines of the below for getting the most recent approver:

```
@NonCPS
def getLatestApprover() {
   def latest = null

   // this returns a CopyOnWriteArrayList, safe for iteration
   def acts = currentBuild.rawBuild.getAllActions()
   for (act in acts) {
       if (act instanceof org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.steps.input.ApproverAction) {
           latest = act.userId
       }
   }
   return latest
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The [JIRA incident](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-31396) referenced u-phoria has been resolved and the fix released.

By setting the submitterParameter to a value, the variable specified by submitterParameter will be populated with the Jenkins user ID that responded to the input field.